# Does upgrading blacksmith cause him to make better stuff?

Tags: diablo-iii

Obviously unlocking crafting items means you can craft those more advanced items. But what does smith levels do? Do they cause him to make the same items but with more armor/damage and special stats or what?

Also, I think I read somewhere that if you have the blacksmith keep making the same item, he will get better at it. Is this wrong?

Original diablo 3, not the souls one. (my friend got original and souls in one for his xbox, so gave me his extra disk)

Answer (score 8):

As you said: you can craft those more advanced items. Most recipes you can teach him also require him to be at a certain level. Those are the only benefits that are connected to leveling the blacksmith.

The quality of one specific item always stays the same, the blacksmith does *not* get better at making a specific item after making it a lot.

The lower level items will always be of the same quality as when you first unlock them. So if you can craft a level 21 item, it will always have level 21 stats, regardless of the level of your blacksmith.

This is the same for RoS or the basegame. The only thing RoS did was give the blacksmith two more levels and more/different recipes.

Comment: Just beat me to it, much better answer than mine though.

Comment: RoS? The recipes to teach him, you get those as random drops?

Comment: RoS = Reaper of Souls (the expansion). Recipes do indeed drop as random drops.